# Finish or destroy of activity on clicking of Listview button after starting of Another activity

Tags: android, baseadapter, activity-finish, getview

I have an Activity ListActivity having Listview and another class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter.

Code in ListActivity

```
customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(list);
TripList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

In getView() of CustomListAdapter I inflate a layout. there is a button and on click of that button I am starting another activity.

I want to finish ListActivity after start of another activity.
With the below code My app is crashing.

```
((Activity) ctx).finish();
```

Log is

```
01-05 11:06:04.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 11:06:04.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4319): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 4319
01-05 11:06:04.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4319): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 11:06:04.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4319):     at com.example.myapp.CustomListAdapter$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:71)
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: okay ,then post your logcat

Comment: Are you try with **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);** , don't use **finish()** in this case

Comment: #manjari : Check my answer .let me feedback please .

Answer (score 4):

At first ,You can post your  <kbd>Logcat</kbd>  .

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**

> if used to start the root activity of a task, it will bring any
>   currently running instance of that task to the foreground, and then
>   clear it to its root state.

You can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

**Finally** ,It should be ,

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NewActivityName.Class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry , Its Not working  . After pressing back button of device that activity is again displaying.

Comment: Its giving error  this  "The method finish() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: @manjari Ji . Its okay .Can you post your total code ? you are getting now `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks . It was solved . As i was starting an activity inside getView() so only finish() did not work. I just changed it to ((Activity)parent.getContext()).finish();

Answer (score 3):

**Replace** your activity name with new activity .

```
startActivity(new Intent(ctx,NewActivity.class));
((Activity) ctx).finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

As i was starting an activity inside getView() so
`((Activity) ctx).finish();`  was not working. I just changed it to `((Activity)parent.getContext()).finish();` and it was working

Comment: Happy coding . Move on .